# Opening files locally from web application

Tags: c#, asp.net, file

I recently added a way for my web application (ASP.NET written in C#) to go to a folder which contains a bunch of spreadsheets and import them into SQL server tables.  I set the folders and file names using an admin table so it knows how to handle each file and which table they should go to etc.  It even keeps track of the file dates and times so it ignores anything that isn't new since the last time it imported them.  Very cool but it only works on my development machine, most likely because the path is easily recognized there.

I'd like others to be able to do this but I can't seem get the web application to access a pre-arranged path on the users local machine.  Now I'm assuming this is normal (we shouldn't be able to have a web application reach into someone's machine and grab files!)  but is there some way to either do it using a known path or by having a user select the local folder?  Is it possibly done more easily if I put the files in a folder within the site?

Dana

Comment: Your web application just needs the necessary permissions in order to do it. Shouldn't be too hard if you're in a corporate network. But if I were you, I wouldn't do it through folder monitoring. I'd make it so the user has to explicitly upload files. Of course, that all depends on a number of factors, but I try to avoid accessing files over the SMB protocol whenever possible. HTTP has been much faster.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, the approach is that you want a user to type in a local file path and you process it.

This will not work through a website. And from a security perspective this is very wise as you point out. So unless you install some client application on the local machine it is not possible.

You will need a file-upload dialog and have the user explicity locate the files for you, click upload and process them on the server.

Some other strategies here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_files_from_web_applications
but it still requires the user to select them manually.

Comment: Thank you, I will try to go down that road.  Safe to say any folder on the website is easily found by the application?  It's some standard file path: http://xxxx etc?

Comment: @Pleun Your answer assumes this is a public web server. But the answer doesn't take into account that this could be a web application located on a server in a corporate network, where the account the web application is running as may have access to file systems of the clients. There does not *have* to be an application installed on the client machine.

Comment: @mason but then the user has to type a complete UNC path including the machine name - the account only exists on the backend and will not have that acces level through the browser... In theory the web application could run as a domain admin but still the browser cannot do anything.

Comment: @Plen Again, your thought process is approaching this from a general web standpoint and not a corporate environment standpoint. The server side is fully capable of accessing a system (probably DB) which identifies which machine a user is on. I agree with you that it's not an ideal solution, but it is fully possible to do it. So saying "this will not work through a website" is inaccurate, and I believe you should update your answer to reflect that.